# Are there are infinitely many primes of the form $n!+p$ for every prime $p$ greater than $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I arrived at this idea by considering the proof of infinitude of primes. Please help me in proving this result or any other related results. 
Example: the most famous question is when $p$ is not prime that is $k=1$. But for other numbers it is difficult to prove.

Comment: I'm not sure the question is well-posed.  Since $p$ has to be greater than $n$, it seems $n$ is chosen and fixed first, and we might be asking for infinitely many $p$.  But since the quantifier is "for every" on $p$, it seems we pick $p$ first and ask for infinitely many $n$ (which there can't be, since $n$ is bounded by $p$.)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking. If you mean "for each $p$ there are infinitely many primes of the form $n!+p$, where $p>n$", then this is obviously false because for every $p$ there are only finitely many choices for $n<p$. (Of course if $n\geq p$ the resulting number is not prime.) If you mean "for each $n$ there are infinitely many primes of the form $n!+p$, where $p>n$" then this is a [famous unsolved problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TwinPrimeConjecture.html) even for $n=2$.